# Date Modified in document library explorer view is not correct

Tags: 2007, document-library

When viewing certain document libraries, and their documents through the explorer view, the date modified column is not showing the same date as the modified column in the web view.

The web view, as far as we can tell, is correct.

In addition version history, is not showing any changes to the documents, and our users are not recalling any changes to either documents or their metadata.

Why is the explorer view different, and can we correct it?

Answer (score 2):

The explorer view is looking at the date modified property of the file and not the sharepoint date modified column.  So when a file is copied into SharePoint, the date modified column is updated in SP but the date modified property of the file itself is not updated because the file hasn't actually changed it's contents.

Comment: Looking at the explorer view and sharepoint view this doesn't seem to be the case, as for example one of the files was not updated on the date shown in the explorer view, with a later date then what is shown in the version history.

Comment: In explorer view, just like when you are browsing on your computer, when you right click and select properties of the file, that modified date that is listed there, does it have the same date that is showing in explorer view?

Comment: yes, however the date shown in the explorer window (02/09/2011), and the file properties, does NOT appear in the version history of the document, which shows the last edit of the file occurred on 31/08/2011.

Comment: I understand.  The version history is a SharePoint feature which will also include changes to the file and any metadata about the file.  Metadata changes will not change the date modified property of the file itself but will change the date modified column in SP.  

I'm just trying to explain what you are seeing.  I'm not saying that it is correctly implemented or intuitive.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. I'm just failing to understand why the explorer view has a later date then the version history date.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about other Windows versions but in Win 7, 'Date Modified' does not show the date it was modified in Sharepoint 2010. In Windows Explorer, right click the header and choose 'Date last saved', which will show the Sharepoint last modified date.

Answer (score -1):

There are 3 types of date attributed to a file, the date created, the date accessed (only shows in properties dialog box I believe) and the modified date.
Creation date and modification date are very important but needs to be turn on or off to be able to view. By default Explore shows the created date when files in a folder are viewed by way of details as opposed to list.
When in details view right click on the date showing above the dialog box to pull down the the options and uncheck or check to turn on and off types of date attributed to the files.
I usually just turn on date modified so I always know when a files was touched or worked on by someone!
Thanks